# Is there a way to put this bent leg straigt?

Tags: mesh

So I have this little fox leg as a mesh, and I want it to put it straight.

[image]

I tried using bone or curve modifier, but the result was not very satisfying.
The bones simply split a big curve into two smaller curves, which is not nice enough for me.

[image]

I see that there are many ways to bent a straight object real nice, but it seems difficult for me to find a good way to put a bent mesh straight. Any advices?

P.S: Here is the .blend file, should you be interested.
[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try using proportional editing! ([Blender docs](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/controls/proportional_editing.html))

This requires doing some work by hand, but it might be worth a go when your needs are very specific and you're confident you could eyeball it.

0. Always back up your work before making big changes, of course!
1. In this case, start with a head-on camera angle, because it's an easy way to make sure things don't move along the wrong axis. I chose Front Orthographic.
2. Go to edit mode, and enable proportional editing, which is this bullseye looking icon near the top middle:

[image: Circle over icon for proportional edit, which looks like a bullseye near the top of the screen]

3. Select a portion of your mesh (just pick randomly at first to play around!) and move, rotate, or scale it. Before you click the mouse button to confirm your movement/rotation/scale, use the mouse wheel to adjust how strong the proportional edit is.

[image: Using the mouse wheel mid-transform in order to demonstrate the effects of different proportional edit radiuses]

Try out different sections until you start to reach the intended result!

[image: moving just the knee]

[image: moving a "horizontal slice" of the leg]

My janky result from one attempt...

[image: I worked very fast, so the results are a little jagged and uneven looking.]

Depending on your use case, you could use sculpting tools, such as "Smooth," to even things out.

[image: using sculpting "smooth" brush on an edge of the leg]

P.S. Don't forget to turn proportional editing off when you're done.

P.P.S. That's a cute fox!

Comment: Thank you for your attention, and it works! Guess who's cuter than this fox? That's you~

Answer (score 5):

You can ty (not already so new) *Sculpt brush* > **Pose**

[image]

... and polish with **Smooth** brush.

[image]

BTW ... would be more efficient to simplify or retopo your model it saves you a lot of process headaches :)